# How to align div on boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using boostrap.I want to do below this example with bootsrap.

Desktop view(xxl-xl-lg-md)

Mobile view(sm)

How can I do do this?Please help me.Thank you

[image]

Note:I'm using laravel.Boostrap script and template comig layout

```
<style >
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="width:100%">
    <div class="col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xxl-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="background-color:red;color:white;">
          div1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xxl-12 col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="background-color:blue;color:white;">
            div 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxl-8 col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="background-color:orange;">
      <img src="/Images/GUVENLIK_VE_KAMERA/Guvenlik_Kamerasi.png" class="center" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What have You done alone so far? Could You provide Your code please ?

Comment: Of course I'll share

Comment: can you please review